# Integral with unknown part

Tags: definite-integrals

if I have an area between two curves, f(x)=x^2 and g(x)=x^(1/2)
would there be a way to algebraically calculate 1/4 of the area and show it in two different parts of the area starting from the bottom intersect? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kR1Oa.jpg) Hopefully this image helps with understanding the question I'm asking? each line represents 1/8th

Comment: Since the two lines intersect after 4 ticks, I assume each line represents 1/4, not 1/8, right?

Comment: the question asks us to make the area 1/4 of the shaded colour and if there are two different equal shaded parts it will be equal to 1/8 for each of them

Comment: No idea what that last comment is supposed to mean.

Comment: so the question asked us to have 1/4th of the total area to be shaded, and if the shaded are is split into two equal parts it would be 1/8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well you want that the area between the line and the parabola is $\dfrac{1}{8}$ of the area between the two parabolas.

We first compute the area between the two parabolas
$$A=\int_0^1 \left(\sqrt{x}-x^2\right) \, dx=\left[\frac{2 x^{3/2}}{3}-\frac{x^3}{3}\right]_0^1=\dfrac{1}{3}$$

Now we want to find a line $y=mx$ such that the area between the line and the parabola is $\dfrac{1}{8}\,A=\dfrac{1}{24}$.

First we find the intersection point between the line and the parabola

$x^2=mx\to x=m$ so we must have

$$\int_0^m \left(m x-x^2\right) \, dx=\frac{1}{24}\to \frac{m^3}{6}=\frac{1}{24}\to m=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{4}}$$

In a similar way we find  the other line $y=px$ which intersects the other parabola in $x= \frac{1}{m^2}$

$$\int_0^{\frac{1}{m^2}} \left(\sqrt{x}-m x\right) \, dx=\frac{1}{24}\to \frac{1}{6 m^3}=\frac{1}{24}\to m=\sqrt[3]{4}$$

Hope this helps

[image]

Comment: what do the arrors mean and how did you get to (m^3)/6?

Comment: can you help with this?

Comment: @flynnswift It's just a remake of your picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/kR1Oa.jpg  I tried to understand: it's YOU who need to help ME :)

Comment: Thank you so much @Raffaele, big help man!

Comment: $\int \left(m x-x^2\right) =\frac{m x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}$ then plug $m$ and you get the definite integral $\frac{m^3}{2}-\frac{m^3}{3}=\frac{m^3}{6}$

Comment: what if it was to the power of 4 instead of power of 2? how would that be done?

Comment: @flynnswift the line intersects at $x^4=mx\to x=\sqrt[3]{m}$ the area must be $1/8$ of $\dfrac{3}{5}$ and the result is $m=\dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt[5]{2}}$

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the two integrals to get 1/cuberoot 4 and cuberoot 4. would you be able to go into depth with them for me please?

Comment: @flynnswift $ \frac{1}{6 m^3}=\frac{1}{24}\to 6m^3=24\to m^3=4\to m=\sqrt[3]{4}$

Comment: what do the arrors mean in your answers?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to solve
$$
\int_0^y x^{\frac{1}{2}} - ax = \frac{A}{8}
$$
where A denote the total area between both curves, and y is the root of $x^1/2-ax$, i.e $y=\frac{1}{a^2}$.

If I'm not mistaken, you should obtain $a=\sqrt[3]{4}$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. The motive of this website is to lead people towards a possible solution by giving out hints. So it would be better if you can show how your reached the answer rather than the final answer itself.